# Shift the origin from (0,0) to (0,50) in JFreeChart

Tags: java, graph, jfreechart, linechart

As shown in image the graph is from line y=0, here i want to plot a graph from y=50, how can i specify this in `JFreeChart`?
 [image: JFreeChart]

Here is Some Code:

```
public class Profile  {



    double last=0;
    public void generateProfile(int[] pointValue,double[] distance){
        ArrayList pv=new ArrayList();
        ArrayList dist=new ArrayList();

        pv.add(pointValue);
        dist.add(distance);
        for(int i=0;i<pv.size();i++){
            System.out.print(pointValue[i]);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<dist.size();i++){
            System.out.print(distance[i]);
        }


        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Average Weight");
        for(int i=0;i<pointValue.length;i++){
            if(pointValue[i]!=0){

              series.add(last,pointValue[i]);
              last=distance[i];
            }
         }


      XYDataset xyDataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
      JFreeChart chart;

      chart= ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart("Profile View Of Contour", "Distance", "Contour Value", xyDataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
      ChartFrame frame1=new ChartFrame("XYLine Chart",chart);
      frame1.setVisible(true);
      frame1.setSize(300,300);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the bottom value of the Y axis with the setLowerBound() method of the ValueAxis class.

Using your example:

```
JFreeChart chart;
chart = ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart("Profile View Of Contour", "Distance", "Contour Value", xyDataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);

ValueAxis rangeAxis = chart.getXYPlot().getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setLowerBound(50.0f);
```